# WebRTC to make calls to PTSN

Tags: sip, voip, webrtc

I'm looking at WebRTC and I'm wondering how to implement a solution where the client connects to the PTSN via SIP. It seems like a pretty new technology so I assume that this would not work on IE browsers; is this correct?

Basically, I have a dialpad UI on the page and users who have an SIP account. Can WebRTC enable the end-user to make calls to the PTSN and what does it take to implement such solution?

I'm looking into this as an alternative to Java or Flash based webphones.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: WebRTC extension for IE - http://code.google.com/p/webrtc4ie/ - (Internet Explorer 9 and later)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebRTC is indeed new and isn't available on IE or Safari. It is available in beta/alpha on other browsers. IE will probably support it in the future and Safari probably won't for some time.

WebRTC does only the media parts of the negotiation, and as such it means that it does no signaling of its own. SIP can work well with WebRTC, but you will need a JS implementation of SIP (over WebSockets) and then you'll need to unwrap the SIP signaling on the server side and "migrate" it to UDP or TCP.
Asterisk are working on such a server side platform: http://blogs.digium.com/2012/05/23/asterisk-11-webrtc/

More about doing SIP in conjunction with WebRTC can be found here: http://bloggeek.me/html-sip/

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Seems that for the moment, a java or flash SIP webphone would be a better option until all this matures?

Comment: that really depends on when and in what kind of a setup do you want your solution to work.

Comment: My solution needs to work in IE8 so I guess WebRTC will be a phase 2 implementation.

Comment: Another option is to add it as a plugin, similar to what you're actually doing with Flash or Java (but in this case, you need the user to install your plugin and not something as common as Flash).

Comment: What is/are the webphone(s) that you'd recommend?

Comment: For WebRTC that would be http://www.sipml5.org/. I haven't used it but I think it is the only one. For Flash and Java I really have no experience.

Comment: Just to say -- the WebRTC APIs are now supported in Chrome stable (flagless) and Firefox Nightly. Take a look at www.webrtc.org/demo.